# Error about Autobiographer badge

Tags: discussion, badges

I filled all the details(fields) in my profile and got "Autobiographer badge". But if I 
undo the changes the badge is still part of my profile. Below is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer?userid=2168706

Is this a bug and if it is, can it be solved?

Comment: Badges are to encourange good behaviour, there was good behaviour, why would the badge be taken back?

Answer (score 7):

This is by design. Once the badge is awarded is not taken back except tag badges.

Comment: don't you think this is an issue in the design?

Comment: @juergend - Your comment and the last three words of my answer are same :D

Comment: Am I blind or did you edit that in :)

Comment: Nope @SantoshSahu: If we start taking back the badges, we have to award the same badge again and again whenever it qualify.

Comment: @juergend that's graceness for you! (vs. blindness if you missed the punch line ;-))

Comment: @sha - it's a blindness :-) (I have not edited during the grace period)

Comment: @hims056 prove it! :-D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - [Here you go...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7WJms.png)

Comment: Nice one, lol!!